# How to retrieve huge set of dataset from Teradata using Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, teradata, spring-jdbc

I am trying to get huge records from Teradata. Approximately 2 million records.

Whats the best approach to retrieve and process using Spring 4?

Is there any way to make split and make parallel request?

Comment: JDBC Fast Export may be your best option without having access to use the native Teradata utilities such as Teradata Parallel Transport or FastExport (CLI-based).

Comment: Here's some information about [JDBC FastExport](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BGBFBBEG).